# Question about multi-inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
#define MNAME 30
class Person {
public:
    char name[MNAME + 1];
};
class Student : public Person {
};
class Staff : public Person {
};
class Faculty : public Student, public Staff {
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Faculty faculty;
    cout << "Address of faculty.Person::name: " << &faculty.Person::name << endl;
    cout << "Address of faculty.Student::name: " << &faculty.Student::name << endl;
    cout << "Address of faculty.Staff::name: " << &faculty.Staff::name << endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When executed, the program gives the results:

```
Address of faculty.Person::name: 0012FF20 // **Line 1**
Address of faculty.Student::name: 0012FF20 // **Line 2**
Address of faculty.Staff::name: 0012FF3F // **Line 3**
```

I don't get it. Why the address in `Line 1` and `Line 2` is different from `Line 3`, while both Student and Staff inherits name from Person?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With regular multiple inheritance you get multiple copies of shared base classes.  If you want one copy, use virtual inheritance.

Explained well in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)

```
class Student : public virtual Person {
};
class Staff : public virtual Person {
};
```

Will get you what you expected

Answer (score 13):

When you do multiple inheritance this way you get two copies of the grandparent class. This is the classic [dreaded diamond](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.8) problem, where you try to do this:

```
        Person
       /       \
     Student  Staff
       \       /
        Faculty
```

but through normal inheritance you actually get this:

```
    Person   Person
      |        |
     Student Staff
       \       /
        Faculty
```

So there's really 2 Person's in an instance of Faculty, meaning youll get 2 names.

To get the diamond in the first diagram above, you want to use [virtual inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.9).

```
class Staff : public virtual Person {
};
class Student : public virtual Person {
};
```

Comment: +1 for most detailed answer. I think this one should be accepted

Answer (score 2):

you are inheriting from the two different classes separately.

you should use [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

You've encountered the classic diamond inheritance problem. Due to the way multiple inheritance work in C++ there are actually *two* distinct copies of `name` in `Faculty`. This can typically be solved by using virtual inheritance like this, so you only have one instance of `Person` and its members:

```
class Student : public virtual Person {
};
class Staff : public virtual Person {
};
```

I'm pretty sure in this case however you don't want to do this. It doesn't seem reasonable to assume that every `Faculty` is also a `Student` AND a `Staff` member, so you shouldn't represent it in this way. It seems plausible that a `Faculty` would always be a `Staff`, so you could use single inheritance to model that relationship. Then if needed, factor out (into free functions or a separate class) the common code from student that's also needed in `Faculty`.

Answer (score 0):

`class Faculty` inherits two sub objects of `class Person`, one through `class Student` and another through `class Staff`.

`&faculty.Staff::name` returns address of the sub object of `class Person` derived through `class Staff`.

`&faculty.Student::name` returns address of the sub object of `class Person` derived through `class Student`.

Both are different sub objects and hence the different address.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple inheritance your derived class `faculty` has 2 copies of `Person`. 1st through `Student` and 2nd through `Staff`.

When you refer `faculty.Person::name`, it refers either via `Student` or via `Staff`. This is an **ambiguous** situation and even will not compile with g++.

In MSVC, it seems that since `Faculty` inherits `Student` first and then `Staff`, it's referring `faculty.Person::name` as `facutlty ==> Student ==> Person ==> name`. That's why output of first 2 lines are same and 3rd line is different.

Answer (score 0):

A bit off topic but....Most experienced developers avoid multiple inheritance.  It is difficult to maintain and fraught with peril.